# Reliably fetching opengraph data from websites like facebook, twitter, and others

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, twitter, facebook-opengraph, cloudflare

I'm to populate the opengraph data from a list of websites that I have stored in a database. Like facebook pages, twitter, pages, personal websites, etc

However, I keep encountering problems when just sending raw requests to the pages. Facebook eventually stops returning opengraph data (the `og:title` is just "Log in to Facebook | Facebook" and the `og:description` is "Log in to Facebook to start sharing and connecting with your friends, family and people you know."), personal websites often have cloudflare blocking requests, etc

What is the best way to fetch this kind of data, perhaps with some kind of user agent that people have agreed on? I've tried using a residential proxy service instead of fetching directly via axios, however they are very expensive, and repeatedly loading large webapps like facebook, even when blocking images, is very data expensive.

Googling this only seems to return results of people trying to share opengraph data, not read it